# How could we display a text with a picture when we click on an image thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to display a text with my picture when I click on my thumbnail picture and I wrote a method to do something like this, but I don't know why my text can't appear on my web site. 
Because I created a method in my JS to display the text under the thumbnails, and I called this function in my template part of JS.
Can you help me please?

[image]

```
Vue.component('carousel', {
    template: `
        <div class="card-carousel" >
            <div class="thumbnails">
                <div 
                    v-for="(image, index) in  images"
                    :key="image.id"
                    :class="['thumbnail-image', (activeImage == index) ? 'active' : '']"
                    @click="activateImage(index)" @click="activateText(index)">
                    <img :src="image.thumb">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="containe-carousel">

            <div class="photoshop-screenshot">                
            <img :src="currentImage"  alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card-img">
                <img :src="currentImage2" alt="">

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    computed: {

        currentImage() {
            return this.images[this.activeImage].big;
        },

        currentImage2() {
            return this.images[this.activeImage].big2;
        },

        currentText (){
            return this.texts[this.activeText].text;
        }

    },

    data() {
        return {
            activeImage: 0,
            activeText :0,
        }
    },

    methods: {     
        activateImage(imageIndex) {
            this.activeImage = imageIndex;
        },  

        activeText (imageIndex){
            this.activeText = imageIndex;
        }
    },

    props: ['images', 'texts']
})





    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data() {
                return {
                    images: [

                        {
                            id: '1',
                            big: '/images/keyboard1/photoshop-profile.PNG',
                            big2: '/images/keyboard1/photoshop-screenshot.png',
                            text : 'photo 1',
                            thumb: '/images/keyboard1/photoshop-logo.jpg'
                        },
                        {
                            id: '2',
                            big: '/images/keyboard2/autocad-profile.png',
                            big2: '/images/keyboard2/autocad-screenshot.png',
                            text : 'photo 2',
                            thumb: '/images/keyboard2/autocad-logo.png'
                        },
                        {
                            id: '3',
                            big: '/images/keyboard3/counterstrike-profile.png',
                            big2: '/images/keyboard3/counterstrike-screenshot.jpg',
                            thumb: '/images/keyboard3/counterstrike-logo.png'
                        },
                        {
                            id: '4',
                            big: '/images/keyboard4/leagueoflegends-profile.png',
                            big2: '/images/keyboard4/leagueoflegends-screenshot.png',
                            thumb: '/images/keyboard4/leagueoflegends-logo.jpg'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

CSS:

```
.section{
    background-color: black;
}

.card-carousel {
    user-select: none;
    position: relative;
}


.thumbnails {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-direction: row;

}

.thumbnail-image {
    display: fixed;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 2px;
}

.thumbnail-image > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: all 250ms;
    filter: grayscale(100%);

}

.thumbnail-image:selected> img {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    visibility: hidden;
    filter: none;
}


.card-img {
    position: relative;
}

 .card-img > img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 7%;
    z-index: 2; 
}

 .photoshop-screenshot {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 70%;
    right:-80px;
    bottom:-130px;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you don't need to texts in `props` object and you have duplicated `@click` event  i cleaned up the unnecessary parts from your code:

```js
Vue.component('carousel', {
    template: `
        <div class="card-carousel" >
            <div class="thumbnails">
                <div 
                    v-for="(image, index) in  images"
                    :key="image.id"
                    :class="['thumbnail-image', (activeImage == index) ? 'active' : '']"
                    @click="activateImage(index)">
                    <img :src="image.thumb"/>
                    <caption>{{image.text}}</caption>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="containe-carousel">
          
            <div class="photoshop-screenshot">                
            <img :src="currentImage.big"  alt="">
                    <caption> {{currentImage.text}}</caption>

            </div>
            <div class="card-img">
                <img :src="currentImage2.big2" alt="">
                    <caption> {{currentImage2.text}}</caption>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    computed: {

          currentImage() {
            return this.images[this.activeImage];
        },

        currentImage2() {
            return this.images[this.activeImage];
        }
     
    },

    data() {
        return {
            activeImage: 0,
          
        }
    },

    methods: {     
        activateImage(imageIndex) {
            this.activeImage = imageIndex;
        },  
        
      
    },
   
    props: ['images']
})
```

There's the [demo](https://nr99nqk2qm.codesandbox.io/)   and the [source code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nr99nqk2qm) , i just used single file component but it doesn't matter